# How to listout the item list for same order (in food order) and show in table using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am in Hackathon and doing food ordering system using Mysql and php, I need to list out the items ordered by a customer and display in table.

I have three table in xampp (customers,orders,products), I join them and get

[image: current output]

but I want to show table like this.
[image: required table]

what should I do in PHP looping condition to show the required result table?
please help.

currently I take the data form database as:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>customer_id from<br>   customers table</th>
        <th>customer_id from <br>orders table</th>
        <th>product_id from <br>product table</th>
        <th>seat_no from <br> customer table</th>
        <th>product name from <br> product table</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      $selectquery = " SELECT customers.seat_no,customers.id,orders.customer_id,orders.product_id,products.product_id,products.name from customers,orders,products WHERE customers.id=orders.customer_id and products.product_id = orders.product_id  ORDER BY customers.id,orders.customer_id";

      $query = mysqli_query($con, $selectquery);
      while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      ?>

        <tr>
          <td> <?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $result['customer_id']; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $result['product_id']; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $result['seat_no']; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And table in xampp are:

customers table:

[image: customers table]

products table:
[image: products table]

orders table:
[image: orders table]

Comment: Edit your question and add the table definition and the query you are using now.

Comment: done now please review the problem.

Comment: First you need to add order by clause to your query - something like `order by customers.id, orders.id`.  Then try to display it.  If you fail, then edit your question with your new code.

Comment: I edited it now please review once more.

Comment: Vision impaired users cannot read your screenshots.  Please always provide textual question details as copy-pasted (ideally -- formatted) text.  If you want PHP users to be able to handle your sample data accurately and easily, try loading up a demo on https://phpize.online/  Did you try grouping with a composite key? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72000257/2943403  You'll want to push into subarrays instead of concatenating.